# How do I give button peel effect using semantic ui

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

How do I give button peel effect as shown in the attached file. I am using semantic ui based button and would like the effect on my button which shows a bit of coupon code. Below is the code which I use in semantic ui

```
<a class="ui green button" id="working">View Deal</a>
```

I want something as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple On Hover Peel Off Animation Using **pure** CSS

```css
.anim750{
  transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
}

#Awesome{
 position: relative;
 width: 180px;
 height: 180px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#Awesome .sticky{
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#Awesome:hover .sticky{
 transform: rotate(10deg);
}

#Awesome .sticky{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width:180px;
 height: 180px;
}

#Awesome .reveal .circle{
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', arial;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Awesome .reveal .circle{
 background: #fafafa;
}

#Awesome .circle_wrapper{
 position: absolute;
 width: 180px;
 height: 180px;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#Awesome .circle{
 position: absolute;
 width: 140px;
 height:  140px;
 margin: 20px;
 
 border-radius: 999px;
}

#Awesome .back{
 height: 10px;
 top: 30px;
}

#Awesome:hover .back{
 height: 90px;
 top: 110px;
}

#Awesome .back .circle{
 margin-top: -130px;
 background-color: #fbec3f;

 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(251,236,63,.0), rgba(255,255,255,.8));
}

#Awesome:hover .back .circle{
 margin-top: -50px;
}

#Awesome .front{
 height: 150px;
 bottom: 0;
 top: auto;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -140px 20px -140px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

#Awesome:hover .front{
 height: 70px;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -60px 10px -60px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

#Awesome .front .circle{
 margin-top: -10px;
 background: #fbec3f;

 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(251,236,63,.0) 75%, #f7bb37 95%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(251,236,63,.0) 75%, #f7bb37 95%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(251,236,63,.0) 75%, #f7bb37 95%);
}

#Awesome h4{
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', arial;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 width: 180px;
 height: 140px;
  line-height: 140px;
 
 transition: opacity 50ms linear 400ms;
}

#Awesome:hover h4{
 opacity: 0;
 
 transition: opacity 50ms linear 300ms;
}

#Awesome:hover .front .circle{
 margin-top: -90px;
 background-color: #e2d439;
 background-position: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Awesome" class="anim750">
 
  <div class="reveal circle_wrapper">
  <div class="circle">Hello!</div>
 </div>
      
 <div class="sticky anim750">
  <div class="front circle_wrapper anim750">
   <div class="circle anim750"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
  <h4>Peel Me!</h4>
      
  <div class="sticky anim750">
  <div class="back circle_wrapper anim750">
   <div class="circle anim750"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can style the `button:after` `border` property.

This is general example with vanilla CSS:

```css
button {position: relative; padding: 10px 20px; background: green; width: 180px; height: 50px; text-align: left; border-radius: 5px;}
button span {position: absolute; right: 5px; text-transform: uppercase; z-index: 2; color: transparent;}
button:hover span { color: grey;} /* same as border color */
button:hover:after {
  content: ' '; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
  /* the effect: */
  border-width: 0 80px 45px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey white;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover to look part of the code</p>
<button>Get Code<span>abcdefg</span></button>
```